# LWC lightning-datatable not displaying related record info

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

I'm trying to create a customized version of a related list in the Partner Community using an LWC.  I am using the following web site as a guide:
https://www.salesforcecodecrack.com/2019/10/display-reference-data-in-lwc.html

It mostly works, but the fields on related records are empty.

HTML:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title={cardTitle}>
        <p class="slds-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-datatable
                key-field="Id"
                data={PartnerPlanTeams}
                columns={columns}
                hide-checkbox-column>
            </lightning-datatable>
        </p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Javascript:

```
import { LightningElement, api, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import init from '@salesforce/apex/PartnerContactRelatedListController.getPartnerPlanTeams';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import PPT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Partner_Plan_Team__c';

const columns = [{label: 'Resource Name', fieldName: 'Name', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Resource', fieldname: 'ResourceNm', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Lookup', fieldName: 'Lookup', type: 'url'},
                {label: 'Role', fieldName: 'Role__c', type: 'text'},
                {label: 'Permissions', fieldName: 'Permissions__c', type: 'text'}
];

export default class PartnerPlanTeam extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
    @track columns = columns;
    @track PartnerPlanTeams;
    @track objectInfo;
    @track cardTitle = 'Partner Plan Teams';

    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: PPT_OBJECT }) objectInfo;

    connectedCallback(){
        console.log(this.recordId);
        this.doInit();
    }

    doInit() {
        init({
            partnerPlanId: this.recordId
        })
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result);
            this.PartnerPlanTeams = [];
            result.forEach((row) =>{
                console.log(row);
                let rowData ={};
                rowData.Id = row.Id;
                rowData.Name = row.Name;
                console.log(row.Resource__c);
                if (row.Resource__c)
                {
                    console.log(row.Resource__r.Name);
                    rowData.ResourceNm = row.Resource__r.Name;
                    rowData.Lookup = '/'+row.Resource__c;
                }
                rowData.Role__c = row.Role__c;
                rowData.Permissions__c = row.Permissions__c;

                console.log(rowData);
                this.PartnerPlanTeams.push(rowData);
            });
            console.log('this.PartnerPlanTeams');
            console.log(this.PartnerPlanTeams);
            this.cardTitle = 'Partner Plan Teams (' + this.PartnerPlanTeams.length + ')';
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }
}
```

Apex:

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<Partner_Plan_Team__c> getPartnerPlanTeams(String partnerPlanId){

    if (String.isNotBlank(partnerPlanId))
    {
        List<Partner_Plan_Team__c> listPPT = [SELECT Id, Name, Role__c, Permissions__c, Resource__c, Resource__r.Name FROM Partner_Plan_Team__c WHERE Partner_Plan__c =: partnerPlanId];
        return listPPT;
    } else {
        return new List<Partner_Plan_Team__c>();
    }
}
```

When I view the data in the console log, the ResourceNm attribute is populated, but nothing shows up in the LWC for this column.  All other columns display fine.

Is there a bug in my code that I am missing, or is there some limitation I don't understand?  API version of LWC is 50.

Comment: Finally found the bug: In the "columns" definition, I had typed "filedname" instead of "fieldName".  Needed "N" instead of "n".  Ugh!